# Toggle radios on window scroll up/down

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to toggle radio buttons as the user scrolls up/down the page depending on what section they are viewing.

It correctly toggles them on once, but never checks the if statements again.

I am using `$(window).scroll(function()` to register the scroll position and offset it.

The divs have IDs that are checked in the function call

JSfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w8s7nfpx/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write condition for every element. You can use `$(this)` and `each()` jQuery.

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/w8s7nfpx/10/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#notfixed div").each(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top) {
      $("input[value=" + $(this).attr("id") +
        "]").prop("checked", true);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#notfixed {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

div {
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="selection">1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="selection">2</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="selection">3</label>
</div>

<div id="notfixed">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```